# Keep selected options in multiple select PHP

Tags: php

I need to keep selected the options users choose in a multiple select menu. This is the code I have so far, but still doesnt' work. Thank you for your help!

```
<select name="cb_estatura2[]" size="6" multiple="multiple" class="inputbox" id="cb_estatura2">
<?php 
$height = array("57","58","59","60");
$choosen_height = $_GET['cb_estatura2'];

for ($i=0;$i<count($height);$i++) 
     {
      $selected = ($height[$i] == $choosen_height[$i] ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); 
      echo "<option value='$height[$i]' $selected>$height[$i]</option>";
     } 
?>
</select>
```

Comment: You'll need to use in_array to check if the key ($height[$i]) is in the get variable.

Comment: Im just guessing but I don't think you need the `[$i]` on `$chosen_height`. It's hard for me to tell with out more information but I am guessing that is just suppose to be a integer and not an array.

Comment: Run `print_r($_GET['cb_estatura2']);` and post what it says.

Comment: @Blender, this is the output: Array ( [0] => 57 [1] => 58 [2] => 59 [3] => 60 )

Comment: This code should work. Does it not `echo` anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The one thing that should work would be this:

```
<select name="cb_estatura2[]" size="6" multiple="multiple" class="inputbox" id="cb_estatura2">
<?php 
$height = array("57","58","59","60");
$choosen_height = $_GET['cb_estatura2'];

for ($i=0;$i<count($height);$i++) 
     {
      $selected = (in_array($height[$i],$choosen_height) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); 
      echo "<option value='$height[$i]' $selected>$height[$i]</option>";
     } 
?>
</select>
```

This should work, just for the fact that the `$_GET['cb_estatura2']` doesn't populate like the `$height` array.  Could be wrong, haven't tested it.